# How to Sync Google Fit Data to Apple Health?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, health.app

I'm using a NestHub2 to log my sleep activity which outputs its data to GoogleFit. Is there a way for me to import that data from the Google Fit app into the Health app to use with Sleep?

In the Settings, I've found that sleep allows Google Fit to read data but doesn't pull data from Google Fit itself.

I'm okay with doing weird workarounds as long as it works.

[image: Health Sleep Screenshot]